# Advice on model and method design for creating downloadable products with unique URLs (in Ruby on Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, data-modeling, download

I'm about to embark on a new app that will offer downloads of digital files. To keep the files secure, I never want to give out the exact URL to the end user, but instead want to mask the URL. I also want to generate unique tokens, that preferably, would be made part of the URL so each URL is unique, trackable and expireable, etc.

I guess, in a way, the theory behind URL shorteners would be applicable.

But -- what I'm not sure about is, once I've generate the token and a unique URL for the product, how do I get the rails app to route that unique URL to the actual URL of the product? I've been looking at Sendfile, but I'm not quite sure how best to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the controller action that handles the 'secret' URL, use the `send_file` function, as described in the [API documentation](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.3/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html#M005644).

Comment: So, the controller gets the GET request, checks to see if the token in the URL is valid and that the requester has access to the requested product and then send_file sends the, well file? I'm sure it's more complicated than that, being that the same controller method will be handling downloads for a lot of different products, but am I getting the gist?

Comment: Just make sure wherever the files reside isn't web accessible itself (i.e., not `public`).